# Scroll (custom marquee) textview text inside listview when it doesn't fit

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

What is the best way to accomplish textView scrolling inside listview when it doesn't fit and only when specific row inside listview is selected. Also, I would like my text to scroll from left side to right and when it reaches end to scroll back from right side to left (not default as marquee does)

Xml for ListView row:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtWouldLikeToScroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"  
            android:singleLine="true"
             />
```

I'm using Custom ListViewAdapter and overrided scroll listener:

```
myList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                switch (scrollState) {
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:

                  view.setSelection(positionWhereIwouldLikeToPointSelection);

                    break;
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
                    break;
                case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
                    break;
                }

            }

        });

    }
```

I guess that I have to set textview to be selected (the one I'm setting selection within ListView), and have no idea how to override marquee behavior.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try Animation. It easy to use and will do exactly what u want:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

And now Java code:

```
private TextView mTextView...
private Animation mAnimation...

private void animateTextView() {
    int textWidth = getTextViewWidth(mTextView);
    int maxWidth = ... // Do not know what width you want.

    /* Start animation only when text is longer than dislay width. */
    if(maxWidth<textWidth) {
        mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                0, displayWidth-textWidth,
                0, 0);
        mAnimation.setDuration(3000);    // Set custom duration.
        mAnimation.setStartOffset(500);    // Set custom offset.
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);    // This will animate text back ater it reaches end.
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);    // Infinite animation.

        mTextView.startAnimation(mAnimation);
    }
}

private int getTextViewWidth(TextView textView) {
    textView.measure(0, 0);    // Need to set measure to (0, 0).
    return textView.getMeasuredWidth();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

xml for `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

I assume that you are extending your activity from `ListActivity`. Do the following In your `onListItemClick`

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View row, int position, long id) {

    TextView textViewOne =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textViewOne.setSelected(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if(i!=position){
            View view = (View) parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.view);

            textViewOne = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            textViewOne.setSelected(false);

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly I can't set ListItemClick listener, because TextView (ListView row) have to be selected when ListView ScrollState is Idle (user is scrolling list and on SCROLL_STATE_IDLE I'm indicating row to be selected by listView.setSelection(index).