# Is there a way to restart marquee/scrolling when the last letter of the text becomes visible?

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview, marquee

I want a text inside a textbox to scroll to end and then restart.

Using marquee scrolls the whole text until the first letter reaches the "start point", but I want the text only to scroll until the last letter of the text becomes visible, then pause and the text should jump to start and start scrolling again.

Is there a way to do this. I have search but I can't find something that works for me.

Thanks,
Sebi

Comment: When the last letter becomes visible, are you saying that you want the text to immediately pop back to its initial state with the first letter at the start? In other words, don't scroll the first part of the text from end to start. It is not clear from your description.

Comment: Yes. I want to stop scrolling and after a short pause, the text should jump to start and start scrolling again.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to make the marquee feature of _TextView_ do what you want. Instead, I would take a look at using animation. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15002662/6287910) may help. (I haven't tried it.)

Comment: hmm but the problem is that every animation I saw moves the hole TextView not the text inside the view. (I hope you understand what I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewrite the Code from the GitHub Project [here](https://github.com/hide1202/MarqueeEndTextView) (which was posted in the comment from Cheticamp) to java and shorten it to my needs. Now it starts the animation infinite.

Here the java code:

MarqueeTextView.java:

```
public class MarqueeTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {

private final Scroller mScroller;
private int mDelay;
private int mDuration;
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private final Runnable mAnimateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //check if Animation is needed otherwise check next cycle (if text has changed for example)
        if (getTextViewWidthWithPadding() < getTextWidth()) {
            mScroller.startScroll(getStartX(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
            invalidate();
            int direction = getLayout().getParagraphDirection(0);
            mScroller.startScroll(getStartX(), 0, (getTextWidth() - getTextViewWidthWithPadding()) * direction, 0, mDuration);
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mAnimateRunnable, mDelay);

    }
};

public MarqueeTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public MarqueeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    mScroller = new Scroller(context, new LinearInterpolator());
    setScroller(mScroller);
}

private int getTextWidth() {
    String text = getText().toString();
    TextPaint paint = getPaint();
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    return bounds.width();
}

private int getTextViewWidthWithPadding() {
    return getWidth() - (getPaddingStart() + getPaddingEnd());
}

private int getStartX() {
    boolean isRtl = getLayoutDirection() == LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
    int lineRight = (int) getLayout().getLineRight(0);
    if (isRtl) {
        return lineRight - getTextViewWidthWithPadding();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public void startAnimation(int delay, int duration) {
    mDelay = delay;
    mDuration = duration;
    mHandler.postDelayed(mAnimateRunnable, delay);
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<MarqueeTextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="1. Simple text that shows how to use custom marquee"
    />
```

MainActivty.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((MarqueeTextView)findViewById(R.id.name)).startAnimation(3000, 2000);
}
```

Comment: This looks like the right answer. I would change the `getTextWidth()` merhod to `private int getTextWidth() { return (int) getLayout().getLineWidth(0);}` to avoid the ending fade on the fully scrolled text.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to configure a *TextView* to take on the marquee behavior that you are seeking. The Stack Overflow [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002662/scroll-custom-marquee-textview-text-inside-listview-when-it-doesnt-fit) I referred you to in the comments does translate the entire *TextView*. I think that this will work as a marquee if you set the *TextView* within a *ViewGroup* such that the *TextView* is clipped. You can also do you own clipping. You would have to try this to see if it would work. If this does work, it may be sufficient for your needs, but you may be missing the fading edge and maybe some other characteristics of true marquee scrolling. Also, some other characteristics of the *TextView* such as shadows, borders and backgrounds might not look right.

The contents of the *TextView* is animated by the *TextView* code itself through canvas translation for marquee scrolling. See [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;l=8340?q=textview&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject).

```
if (isMarqueeFadeEnabled()) {
    if (!mSingleLine && getLineCount() == 1 && canMarquee()
            && (absoluteGravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) != Gravity.LEFT) {
        final int width = mRight - mLeft;
        final int padding = getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getCompoundPaddingRight();
        final float dx = mLayout.getLineRight(0) - (width - padding);
        canvas.translate(layout.getParagraphDirection(0) * dx, 0.0f);
    }

    if (mMarquee != null && mMarquee.isRunning()) {
        final float dx = -mMarquee.getScroll();
        canvas.translate(layout.getParagraphDirection(0) * dx, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

You can also consider writing a custom *TextView* and doing your own text scrolling. You can look to the *TextView* code itself for some tips on how you might do it. I think writing your own *TextView* would have better results. (IMO)

Comment: Hi, I will test it. And yes the last hope is to create my own textview.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/hide1202/MarqueeEndTextView) is a GitHub project that seems to do what you want. I haven't used it or even tried it. I thought I would just mention it here in case it is of use to you.

Comment: One more [link](https://0202gaurav.medium.com/marquee-behavior-in-textview-android-81b17bbb6dfd) to show how animation can be done. Again, I haven't tried this method but it comports with what I posted in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub Link. It looks like as it is what I want. :)